# How do I add a filter to wp_list_categories() to make links nofollow?

Tags: plugin-development

How can I add a rel="nofollow" attribute to my category widget listings?

I'm currently filtering the call to wp_list_categories with this code in my functions.php...

```
function my_wp_list_categories($cat_args){
    $cat_args['title_li'] = '';
    $cat_args['exclude_tree'] = 1;\
    $cat_args['exclude'] = 1;
    $cat_args['use_desc_for_title'] = 0;
    return $cat_args;
    }
add_filter('widget_categories_args', 'my_wp_list_categories', 10, 2);
```

Update: When I try this...

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories','wp_rel_nofollow');
```

My links come out with escape slashes...

```
<li class=\"cat-item cat-item-5\">
  <a href=\"http://mysite/category/chinese-tea/\" title=\"View all...Chinese Tea\" rel=\"nofollow\">Chinese Tea</a>
</li>
```

Comment: wrap your function in `stripslashes()`

Comment: Hey @maugly, for inline code, surround the code with backticks(left of the 1 key).

Comment: @t31os Thanks. I did it now: `$output = str_replace('href=', 'rel="nofollow" href=', $output);` Could something like this be used as a filter?? I tested it and it seems to be working. I just dunno if it's a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories','esc_wp_rel_nofollow');

function esc_wp_rel_nofollow($output){
   return   stripslashes(wp_rel_nofollow($output));
}
```